# Django Queryset: column reference is ambiguous with extra queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-postgresql

I have the next queryset:

```
Article.objects.filter(finished=True, updated_at__range=[start, end]).extra(
    select={'hour': 'extract(hour from updated_at)'}).values('hour').annotate(categorized=Count('id'))
```

And I get the error :

> "ProgrammingError: column reference "updated_at" is ambiguous
>   LINE 1: SELECT (extract(hour from updated_at)) AS "hour", COUNT("art..."

How should I go about this?

Edit:
The queryset works without filtering by date "updated_at__range=[start, end]" but I need that filter.

Answer (score 8):

This is nothing to do with Django. You're inserting raw SQL (the `extract` clause) but failing to qualify the table that updated_at is coming from within it. Assuming the Article model is in an app called "myapp" it would be something like this:

```
select={'hour': 'extract(hour from myapp_article.updated_at)'})
```

Comment: The queryset works without filtering by date "updated_at__range=[start, end]" but I need that filter

Answer (score 7):

If you'd come here through a web search: I started having the error `column reference "created" is ambiguous` when I added `prefetch_related` and `select_related` statements to my filter.

While originally my query `.extra(where=['EXTRACT(hour from created) >19 OR EXTRACT(hour from created) <6'])` worked, it stopped working when select_related/prefetch) was added.

The solution was to add `myappname_mymodelname.` before the field name.

Comment: Just 2 cents: the "mymodelname" for something like "class CaseModel" would be "casemodel"